# Java - program does not want to draw image from subclass

Tags: java, image, graphics

Im just trying to draw a background for my game. I use a 800x600 image of a sky made with Paint.

Quick explanation of this part of the code: StatoGame will draw all the objects that we see in game, MappaReader load the map from a file and TextureReader is used to load images.

This is my code:

(The class that will draw all i see in game)

```
    package main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import lettori.MappaReader;
import lettori.TexturesReader;
import minor.ErrorManager;
import minor.ManipolatoreImmagini;


public class StatoGame {
    public String[][] mappa = new String[25][18];
    public boolean running = false;
    protected ErrorManager EM;  
    GameManager GM;
    public TexturesReader TR;
    public MappaReader MR;
    public void disegna(java.awt.Graphics2D g) {        
        // BACKGROUND PREDEFINITO CON SCRITTA LOADING
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, Game.risoluzioneNativaX, Game.risoluzioneNativaY); 
        Font fontx32 = new Font("Munro Small", Font.PLAIN, 32);
        g.setFont(fontx32);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString("Loading...", 32, 32);
        // -----------------------------------------------
        if (running == true) {      
            g.drawImage(TR.background, 0, 0, Game.risoluzioneFinestraX, Game.risoluzioneFinestraY, null);
            System.out.print("RUNNING!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            // Disegna i blocchi ambientali
            for (int x = 0; x < 25; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < 18; y++) {
                    switch (mappa[x][y]) {
                    case "2":
                        g.drawImage(TR.blocco_erba, x * 32 + 2, y * 32, 28, 32, null);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //ManipolatoreImmagini MI = new ManipolatoreImmagini();
        //BufferedImage background = MI.CreaTrasparenza("Textures/Mappa/background_cielo.png", 255, 0, 255);
        //g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, Game.risoluzioneFinestraX, Game.risoluzioneFinestraY, null);
    }


    public StatoGame(GameManager GMp) {
        GM = GMp;   
        running = false;
        TR = new TexturesReader();
        MR = new MappaReader("Livelli/Selva_Esterna/Livello1/", this);
        running = true; 
    }

    public void keyPressed(int k) {
    }

    public void keyReleased(int k) {
    }

    public void keyTyped(int k) {
    }

}
```

(The class that will load the map. mappaConfigLoader() is not used yet because it is not working.)

```
package lettori;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import main.StatoGame;
import minor.ErrorManager;
import minor.ManipolatoreImmagini;


public class MappaReader {

    String percorsoLivello;
    StatoGame SG;
    ErrorManager EM;
    ManipolatoreImmagini MI;

    public MappaReader(String PL, StatoGame SGp) {

        SG = SGp;
        MI = new ManipolatoreImmagini();
        percorsoLivello = PL;
        mappaLoader();
        //mappaConfigLoader();


    }

    void mappaConfigLoader() {
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(percorsoLivello + "config.ini"))) {
            String riga;
            while ((riga = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (riga.contains("#")) {
                } else if (riga.contains("=")) {
                    StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(riga, "=");
                    boolean ifNomeVariabile = true;
                    String nomeVariabile = "";
                    while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {

                        if (ifNomeVariabile == true) {
                            nomeVariabile = stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString();
                            ifNomeVariabile = false;
                        }                   
                        else {
                            switch (nomeVariabile) {
                            case "background":
                                SG.TR.background = MI.CreaTrasparenza(stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString(), 255, 0, 255);
                                break;
                            }

                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Gestione errori
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            EM = new ErrorManager(e.toString(), "Errore");
            EM = null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            EM = new ErrorManager(e.toString(), "Errore");
            EM = null;
        }
    }





    void mappaLoader() {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(percorsoLivello + "Mappa.txt"));
            String riga;

            int y = 0;

            while ((riga = br.readLine()) != null) {
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(riga, " ");
                int x = 0;
                while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    SG.mappa[x][y] = st.nextToken();
                    x++;
                }
                y++;

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            EM = new ErrorManager(e.toString(), "Errore");
            EM = null;
        }
    }

}
```

(The class that loads images for the game)

```
package lettori;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import main.GameManager;
import main.StatoGame;
import minor.ManipolatoreImmagini;

public class TexturesReader{



    ManipolatoreImmagini MI;
    StatoGame SG;

    // TEXTURES
    // ATTENZIONE : i blocchi normali (esempio blocco_erba),
    // Sono di 28x32 per far si che le decorazioni possano
    // essere disegnate

    public BufferedImage background;
    public BufferedImage blocco_erba;

    public BufferedImage blocco_erba_deco_1;
    public BufferedImage blocco_erba_deco_2;

    public BufferedImage blocco_erba_lato_0;
    public BufferedImage blocco_erba_lato_1;
    public BufferedImage blocco_erba_lato_2;

    public BufferedImage blocco_erba_lato_0_flip;
    public BufferedImage blocco_erba_lato_1_flip;
    public BufferedImage blocco_erba_lato_2_flip;


    public TexturesReader() {

        MI = new ManipolatoreImmagini();

        //background = MI.CreaTrasparenza("Textures/Mappa/background_cielo.png", 255, 0, 255);
        background = MI.CreaTrasparenza("Textures/Mappa/background_cielo.png", 255, 0, 255);
        blocco_erba = MI.CreaTrasparenza("Textures/Mappa/blocco_erba.png", 255, 0, 255);

    }
}
```

The problem is:

when i go in the game from the menu, the graphic will freeze but i can see that the program will write the string "RUNNING!!!!!!!!!!!!" (There is a system output in the class StatoGame to see if the game is running or not.)

If i load a smaller image (for example 100x100px) instead of the original background, it will random works.

If i load an even smaller image of 32x32px instead of the original background, it will always works.

If i delete the code that draws the background, all will work.

If i delete the code that draws the background and i use

```
ManipolatoreImmagini MI = new ManipolatoreImmagini();
        BufferedImage background = MI.CreaTrasparenza("Textures/Mappa/background_cielo.png", 255, 0, 255);
        g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, Game.risoluzioneFinestraX, Game.risoluzioneFinestraY, null);
```

IN THE CLASS STATOGAME to draw it, all will work fine...

So it's clear that there is something goin on with drawing image loaded in other classes.. but if the image is small there is a good probability to make all work. I didn't find a solution. Hope someone can help me.

Sorry for the english and sorry for all this code.